# How to Solve Error Associated with Trusted Authority

Tags: sql-server

This error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=0x80131904
> Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
> Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
> <StackTrace:>
> Inner Exception 1:
> Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

started appearing today when my application tried to connect to the local SQL Server via this connection string:

> "Data Source=ZEKE-XI;Initial Catalog=PIM;Integrated Security=True"

Nothing that I know of has changed on my PC since yesterday when this error did not occur.  Looking at some suggestions in related posts, I tried setting "Server Authentication" to "SQL Server and Windows authentication" but that did not resolve the problem.

SSMS works just fine.

What could be the problem?